# What is the source of not to speak dvarim betelim

Tags: halacha, parshanut-torah-comment, talmud-gemara, torah-study, commentaries

BH

What’s the source and meaning of not speaking dvarim Beteilim purposeless words?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such blanket prohibition, though we are cautioned not to do so excessively or accustom ourselves to it as it easily lapses into forbidden types of speech, or having such types of discussion in the wrong environments (e.g. the synagogue/study-hall).

Comment: [Yoma 19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.19b.10?lang=bi) ("אמר רבא השח שיחת חולין עובר בעשה שנאמר ודברת בם בם ולא בדברים אחרים רב אחא בר יעקב אמר עובר בלאו שנאמר כל הדברים יגעים לא יוכל איש לדבר"). See [here](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/yoma/halachah/yo-hl-019.htm) for interpretations of the force of this, ranging from a biblical prohibition, to a rabbinic prohibition, to a mere ethical exhortation. | Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96367 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88471